# Prevent jquery from appending its own callback

Tags: jquery, jsonp, jquery-callback

I'm trying to call Vimeo's API using `$.ajax()`, but Jquery appends a callback to my URL even when I specify my own named function. I need complete control over the GET URL string.

My code:

```
function fback(data) {
    alert('data = ' + data);
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/group/processing/videos.json?format=jsonp&callback=fback',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    success: fback,
});
```

The GET request goes to:

```
http://vimeo.com/api/v2/group/processing/videos.json?format=jsonp&callback=fback&callback=jsonp1291384300228
```

How can I avoid this automatic callback addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the [`jsonpCallback` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to be the function name you're after, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/group/processing/videos.json?format=jsonp&callback=?',
    jsonpCallback: "fback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    cache: true
});
```

What this does is instead of that randomly generated name (well not so random, but you get the point), it'll use `"fback", resulting in:

```
http://vimeo.com/api/v2/group/processing/videos.json?format=jsonp&callback=fback
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y74rd/).

Comment: jquery is still automatically appending '&callback=fback' part to the GET url. In this case it's the correct function name. But it's still changing my string which is bad since that string needs to be signed. Besides splicing on of the callbacks out of the string after signing, is there any other way to stop two '&callback=fback' substrings from being appended to the GET url?

Comment: @moskovich - did you remove the `success` handler like I did above? :)